# Overriding the plus operator for a user defined vector class in Python

Tags: python, vector

I have written a class to work with three dimensional vectors as follows

```
class vector(object):

def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, z=None, angle=None):

    if angle == None:
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
    if angle != None:
        if angle == "rad":
            self.r, self.theta, self.phi = x, y, z
        if angle == "deg":
            self.r = x
            self.theta = y * 2 * pi / 360.
            self.phi = z * 2 * pi / 360.
        self.x = self.r * sin(self.theta) * cos(self.phi)
        self.y = self.r * sin(self.theta) * sin(self.phi)
        self.z = self.r * cos(self.theta)

def write(self):
    file.write("[" + str(self.x) + ",\t" + str(self.y) + ",\t" + str(self.z) + "]")

def write_sph(self):
    file.write("[" + str(self.mag()) + ",\t" + str(self.gettheta()) + ",\t" + str(self.getphi()) + "]")

def getx(self):
    return self.x
def gety(self):
    return self.y
def getz(self):
    return self.z

def setx(self, x):
    self.x = x
def sety(self, y):
    self.y = y
def setz(self, z):
    self.z = z

def square(self):
    return self.x*self.x + self.y*self.y + self.z*self.z
def mag(self):
    return sqrt(self.square())

def gettheta(self):
    return arccos(self.z / self.mag())
def getphi(self):
    return arctan2(self.y, self.x) # sign depends on which quadrant the coordinates are in

def __add__(self, vector(other)):
    v_sum = vector(other.gettx() + self.gettx(), other.getty() + self.getty(), other.getty() + self.getty())
    return v_sum
```

In the last definition I am attempting to override the operator for addition. The definition works by calling a new vector named other and adding its x,y,z components to the corresponding components of self. When I run the code I'm told the syntax for the definition is invalid. How do I correctly define the vector argument for this overriding definition? Also what difference would changing the definition from def __ add __ to simply def add make? i.e what do the underscores denote?

Comment: `vector(other)` should be simply `other` in function arguments and then inside of the function you can can do: `vector = vector(other)`. BTW Python has something called [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), you're currently trying to code Java in Python. And methods with `__`'s are called [special methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) in Python.

Comment: This hasn't worked. I now get the error: local variable 'vector' referenced before assignment. Did you mean `other = vector(other)` inside the function? This doesn't work either. My coding background is mostly in C++, but I'm learning OOP techniques in Python now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `vector(other)` in your parameter list - just say `other`. Also, you'll need to fix the typos in the add method:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    v_sum = vector(other.getx() + self.getx(), other.gety() + self.gety(), other.getz() + self.getz())
    return v_sum
```